# Paginator not working in laravel 5.2 after upgrading from laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, paginator, laravel-5

My paginator::make() is not working in laravel 5.2 .I also used Length Aware Paginator , nothing works,

```
        $packages = Paginator::make($packages, $totalPackages, $perPage);
```

what is the replacement of that in laravel 5.2

Comment: read the docu https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.0

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? Does it shows any error ?

Comment: You might want to check out this post https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-5-manual-pagination

Comment: yes , its showing that Call to undefined method Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::make()

Comment: where to find product method, it is not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is changed in laravel 5.2 from 5.1. It works exactly like this.

lets say you've table name User and you want to paginate user list

**In Controller**

```
$users = User::all()->paginate(10);  
$users->setPath('users'); //Customise Page Url
return view('users',compact('users'));
```

The setPath method allows you to customize the URI used by the paginator when generating links. For example, if you want the paginator to generate links like http://example.com/custom/url?page=N, you should pass custom/url to the `setPath` method:

**View**

```
{!! $users->render() !!}
```

Comment: Baih , link me galti tha , ho gaya tha

Comment: Mark this answer useful :P